# Scala - Groupby and Max on pair RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new in spark scala and want to find the max salary in each department

```
Dept,Salary
Dept1,1000
Dept2,2000
Dept1,2500
Dept2,1500
Dept1,1700
Dept2,2800
```

I implemented below code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


object MaxSalary {
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Max Salary").setMaster("local[2]"))

  case class Dept(dept_name : String, Salary : Int)

  val data = sc.textFile("file:///home/user/Documents/dept.txt").map(_.split(","))
  val recs = data.map(r => (r(0), Dept(r(0), r(1).toInt)))
  val a = recs.max()???????
})
}
```

but stuck how to implement group by and max function. I am using pair RDD.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using RDDs with the following code:

```
val emp = sc.textFile("file:///home/user/Documents/dept.txt")
            .mapPartitionsWithIndex( (idx, row) => if(idx==0) row.drop(1) else row )
            .map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toString, x.split(",")(1).toInt))

val maxSal = emp.reduceByKey(math.max(_,_))
```

Should give you:

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Dept1,2500), (Dept2,2800))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dataset here is the solution

```
case class Dept(dept_name : String, Salary : Int)


val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Max Salary").setMaster("local[2]"))

  val sq = new SQLContext(sc)

  import sq.implicits._
  val file = "resources/ip.csv"

  val data = sc.textFile(file).map(_.split(","))

  val recs = data.map(r => Dept(r(0), r(1).toInt )).toDS()


  recs.groupBy($"dept_name").agg(max("Salary").alias("max_solution")).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------+
|dept_name|max_solution|
+---------+------------+
|    Dept2|        2800|
|    Dept1|        2500|
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Getting error `value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[MaxSalary.Dept]`

Comment: did you use import spark.implicits._

Comment: No.. Do I need to write anything in sbt because it is returning error `not found: value sqlContext`

Comment: use   val sq = new SQLContext(sc)

  import sq.implicits._

Comment: Now it should work perfectly for your case. See the updated aswer

Comment: OP is using `rdd`, as stated in his question.